# NULL value in designer-generated DataSet throws an exception I don't want

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, dataset

I have a DataSet Designer in my project.

One of my generated datasets has a column which can contain nulls. The database column itself can contain nulls. It's attached to the core table via a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on another column which can, itself, contain nulls.

The designer-generated code which results is this:

```
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Public Property DeptName() As String
        Get
            Try 
                Return CType(Me(Me.tableEmployee.DeptNameColumn),String)
            Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'DeptName' in table 'Employee' is DBNull.", e)
            End Try
        End Get
        Set
            Me(Me.tableEmployee.DeptNameColumn) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

which throws an InvalidCastException when it sees a null. This is **insane**. Of *course* there'll be nulls. I'm expecting them. What I'm not expecting is exceptions being thrown *every time I check the data*.

Is there any way to prompt the Designer to create a `String?` column instead of a `String` column? I mean, the column really should be nullable, to my way of thinking.

I'm connecting to a SQL Server 9.0.50000 installation, which may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a a property on the column name NullValue by default it is set to throw exception. If you set to NULL it should work.[image: Check the property in Attached image]

Comment: Awesome. Bizarre that the designer can't detect this, but nice to find a solution.

Comment: When I, try to change it, msg shows "property value is not valid." I have created dataset from store procedure and column data type is Datetime.